# Creating an empty longitudinal country dataset

Tags: python, pandas, longitudinal

I would like to create an **empty longitudinal country-week-dataset** in which every country is represented 52 times (weeks of the year) and all other variables are first filled with 0s. It should then look like this:

```
countries = ['Albania', 'Belgium', ... 'Zimbabwe']

    df_weekly = {['country': 'Albania', 'week': 1],
['country': 'Albania', 'week': 2],
...
['country': 'Albania', 'week': 52],
...
['country': 'Zimbabwe', 'week': 52]}
```

**My question therefore: how do I get from a list of countries to such a longitudinal country-week-dataset.**

Comment: I would first add a column your `df_data` frame to include the week numbers from the date (using date.isocalendar()[1]), and then aggregate on that value.

Comment: Thank you. That is the plan in general but that would leave out weeks that do not occur in the dataset. But I would like to include those then with the value of 0.

Comment: use panda's function  `groupby`

Comment: That I will. But first it really is about creating the empty dataset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out to be quite simple:

```
country_list = ['Albania', 'Belgium', 'China', 'Denmark']

country = country_list * 52 # multiply by the number of weeks in the year
country.sort()

week = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] * 4 # multiply by the number of countries

weekly = pd.DataFrame(
    {'country': country,
     'week': week
     })
```